# What are the triggers that add new abilities in Trowser shop?

Tags: yooka-laylee

I plan on buying every ability, then going back to W1 and try to complete it 100%, then W2, etc.

Trowser seems to add abilities to his shop every time you open a new world, but are there any other triggers that would add an ability to his shop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is no other trigger that adds abilities to his shop. According to [this wikia page](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Trowzer), the first time you meet him on each world (while travelling up to the book), he grants you an ability for free (that will open the way to the book). Other abilities, in the world, are to be paid.

> If the duo meets Trowzer for the first time in each world, he will
>   give the duo one free move. The player will decide which free move is
>   received.

Then [this guide on Indie Obscura](http://indieobscura.com/article/1077/yooka-laylee-all-trowzer-locations) shows where to find him in each world, with details about which abilities are added, and their price.

For instance, in the thrid world (Moodymaze Marsh), abilities sold are 60 quills each, while when he's on your way to world 4, the ability "camo cloak" will be given for free.

***TL;DR:*** The main answer to your question is no, there isn't any other trigger that adds abilities to Trowzer shop.

Comment: To remove some confusion, when it says 'for the first time in each world' it seems they count the run up to the book as part of the world. You meet Trowser on the way, he gives you a free ability (that will open the way to the book) and then in the world you have to buy his abilities.

Comment: I edited the answer to dismiss confusion, as you suggested.